# Get decode json from URL using php for displaying latest version of fontawesome

Tags: php, json

I want to display latest version of fontawesome versions. But i have a problem with this. My script just display blank page. Please help me.

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://data.jsdelivr.com/v1/package/gh/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$characters = json_encode($data);
echo $characters[0]->versions;

foreach ($characters as $character) {
echo $character->versions . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to add more details.  What is the value of `$data`, of `$characters`.  This would help us, and you might find the issue yourself.  Provide a [mcve] when asking questions.

Comment: @Nic3500 script must display versions of fontawesom from url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code :

```
<?php
$url = 'https://data.jsdelivr.com/v1/package/gh/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome';
$data = file_get_contents($url);

//Use json_decode instead of json_encode
$characters = json_decode($data);

// Use var_dump or print_r to show an object
var_dump($characters->versions);

foreach ($characters->versions as $version) {
    echo $version . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: @DannyOutllet... thank you but script display only "NULL"

Comment: @DannyOutllet... yes i do everything like in your example you can see by yourself at http://veresneva.ho.ua/aw

Comment: @PaulT.  thats' my code, that i just copy for you from my file <?php $url = 'https://data.jsdelivr.com/v1/package/gh/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome';
$data = file_get_contents($url);

//Use json_decode instead of json_encode
$characters = json_decode($data);

// Use var_dump or print_r to show an object
var_dump($characters->versions);

foreach ($characters->versions as $version) {
    echo $version . '<br>';
}?>

Comment: @PaulT. What i must do that you belive me?

Comment: @PaulT. Are you seriuous? This site mask URL in comments... Try to paste full URL in comment a see what happend.

Comment: @АнжеликаДемьяненко If you are getting only NULL that means you have something broken in your code but you don'T have any error or warning. Try to elevate your error log with : https://stackify.com/display-php-errors/
A lot of webserver are disabling `file_get_contents` for security reasons, you might check that first.

Comment: @DannyOuellet..maybe.. and if you are right what can i do  to solve my problem.. is there any way?

Comment: @DannyOuellet i do some change that you recomend about errors and now my script display Warning: file_get_contents(https://data.jsdelivr.com/v1/package/gh/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome): failed to open stream: No route to host in /virt/homes/veresneva/htdocs/aw.php on line 6
NULL ... you can see it here http://veresneva.ho.ua/aw

Comment: This error isn't related to PHP but it might be related to your OS environment. I suggest you to close this question and mark it as resolved and start a new question with theses new informations

Answer (score 0):

Beyond confusing "encode" verse "decode" you may be having another unseen problem, so start with the bare minimum of the following.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://data.jsdelivr.com/v1/package/gh/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump(json_decode($data));
?>
```

The start of the results I am getting from that are:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["tags"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["versions"]=>
  array(50) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "5.9.0"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "5.8.2"
...
```

PHP version information:

```
php --version
PHP 7.3.6 (cli) (built: Jul  3 2019 20:46:48) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.6, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Reproducible with:

```
docker run --rm -i -t php bash
apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
vim test.php
php test.php
```

---

Once debugging was enabled, it appears that network (a proxy or similar) might the your host's issue.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(...): failed to open stream: No route to host
```

Comment: many thankx but your example display "NULL".. you can see by yourself at http://veresneva.ho.ua/aw

Comment: @АнжеликаДемьяненко, I gave you some more information for you to attempt to reproduce the runtime. It seems like you may have a deeper issue with your PHP environment because the code itself is fine.